# Добавить новые элементы в массив в state

Tags: reactjs

```
createNewList = (id, input) => {
   const foundCard = {...this.state.cards.find(card => id === card.id)};
   this.setState(foundCard.list = [...foundCard.list, input]);
  };
```

Привет всем

Есть массив данных (list), который хранится в стейте у каждого объекта (card). Не получается добавлять новый элемент в этот массив.

Способ, которым я пытаюсь делать, создает только один элемент и изменяет его каждый раз. А мне нужно каждый раз создавать новый.
Пробовал создавать отдельный массив, в него добавлять с помощью `newArray.push(input)` и после делать `this.setState(foundCard.list = [...foundCard.list, ...newArray])`, но результат одинаковый.

Redux пока что не использую, так как только начал изучать React и пока что храню все в state.

Заранее спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение

```
createNewList = (id, input) => {
   const newCards = this.state.cards.map(card => {
     if (card.id === id) card.list = [...card.list, input];
     return card;
   });

   this.setState({
     cards: newCards
   });
};
```